# Video recording API in iPhone SDK 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, video-capture, recording

I am working on an app which should allow user to record video on iPhone 3GS.

I was looking into MediaPlayer references but could not find anything there. Can someone give me a head start on the APIs to look for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html), which is basically a dialog box that you can show to let the user either take pictures or record video.